# Drupal Content Types in Liferay

Tags: drupal, liferay

What is the equivalent concept of drupal content type in liferay.

I want to migrate some drupal content types in my Liferay site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't help you on the Drupal side, but Liferay has many different kinds of content: Web Content (the CMS), Blog Entries, Message Board Articles, Documents (and images or other media) and many more. Depending on the data you want to import, you're dealing with any of them. All of these content types can be summarized as Assets, but when you import them to the portal, you'll have to decide for a particular content type.

Further, Liferay's content is totally decoupled from the pages that it's shown on. It gets imported into one (of many possible) sites and can be used from there through many different portlets that can be placed on pages (e.g. "Web Content Display", "Asset Publisher").

Note that you should import the content through Liferay's API - *don't* write directly to Liferay's database.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. How I can show 1 content type as a group on a single page?